# dB scale in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, decibel, scaling

I have a question about the dB scale in Ltspice. As far as I know it uses 1 of the unit (so 1V in case of Voltage) as a reference and then plots the dB value, which is defined by 20*log(V/Vref). (So the lower image is the voltage of my circuit with the y axis property set to dB.)

But when I plot this exact formula in LTspice the plot is actually mirrored at the x-Axis. (Upper plot) Why is that? I think it should be the same. What is my mistake?

Hope you can help!

[image]

Edit: I plottet abs(V(n009)) since the phase is not important for my application and just gives a messy plot. I also have the same problem with any schematic, so I guess the problem has nothing to do with the circuit.

For clarification: easy schematic, same problem (this time it's the current).

[image]

Comment: You can edit your question to make the corrections. There's an edit button to the bottom-left.

Comment: Strange. Obviously the log of a negative number is meaningless, note the 180 degree phase shift of the green plot, so LTSpice is actually plotting log(abs(v)) in the green plot as well. However, I wonder if it's doing something wierd like taking the -ve sign from voltage data and applying it to the dB output??????  -400dB is a rather small number!

Comment: Add the schematic, too, otherwise `V(n009)` is meaningless. It will also help if you renamed the net (`F4`). And I see you're plotting `V(n009)/1`, which doesn't make too much sense. You could also use `V(n009)`, directly, without `abs()`. Not lastly, you have there `-400 dB`, which is `double` precision residual; math with such values is prone to bring numerical inaccuracies.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an LTspice problem, it's the way the waveforms are displayed: *magnitude*, instead of *amplitude*. If you plot `sin(w)`, you won't see a `sin(x)` waveform, but an `abs(sin(x))`. The difference will be in the *phase*: in your plots, the phase appears centered around `180` degrees for the formula, while the "normal" plot shows it's centered around `0`. That's why exporting the waveform will make them "look" fine -- it's a matter of appearance.

Comment: So if I manually take the absolute value of I(V1) and then compute 20*log10(abs(I1)) I get the second Graph.

Comment: and if i take the absolute value from this (second graph) I get the first one.

Comment: @Sandra Look at the phase: in your 1st picture, the upper phase is 180 degrees compared to 0 on the bottom, while in the 2nd, it's an inverted phase compared to the other. If it's more smooth it's probably the way `log()` functions when using complex arguments (`I(V1)`), as opposed to real ones (`abs(I(V1))`). If you use `abs()`, you are really performing `sqrt(re^2+im^2)`, so you are nullifying the imaginary component.

Answer (score 1):

**FTT dBm scale**

In LTspice XVII by default the dB scale is referred to 1V (or 1A or 1W) RMS. The reference of 0.224V gives dBm V(out).
In the FFT window V(out) it is already RMS (Vout/√2). It is NOT the same as V(out) of your schematic. So do not correct to RMS again!
In addition this value is the one that you can get by a bench Spectrum  Analyzer, proper terminated. This means that  LTspice get  the incident wave amplitude (half of RMS input).
If for example you have a 2.0V peak signal you will get -3dB (2.0Vp/√2 = 1.414V rms)  because 20*log(1.414/2)=-3dB ref1V

So if you want to visualize "mathematical" dBm source level in 50Ω load, get V(out) RMS value ((2.0V p/√2 = 1.414V rms), divide by 0,224V and you will get 16dBm, because 20*log(1.414/0.224)=16dBm.
So in FFT window, leave the left vertical axis Magnitude to Bode/dB multiply V(out) times 2 to return the mathematical value of 2.0V (as in your schematic) and divide by 0.224

But if you want to use the FFT window dBm level on a circuit for further calculations (like IP3 etc), then just modify V(out)/0.224 expression on the top of FFT window, and you will get the incident wave dBm amplitude i.e:
(2V/√2)/2=0.707V and 20*log(0.707/0.224)=10dBm

Don't forget: LTspice is developed by scientist...not by engineers!

Answer (score 0):

the formula 20*log10(Vx/Vref) demands Vx and Vref already to be the RMS values.

so taking abs(Vx) should equal Vx - it's squared anyway, as LTSpice will calculate the RMS in background.

In the case you used the formula 20*log10(Vx/Vref) you just "scale" Vx and that is where LTspice then will calculate the RMS from and apply its log-plotting again.

Comment: but for the plots with the formula the y axis is linear

Answer (score 0):

It's an LTspice plot problem, the first graph is just wrong. When exporting the data and plotting the function 20*log10(whatever) it gives the same result as the dB scale in LTspice

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what's wrong is the circuit itself. The voltage source shorts out the capacitor.

The RLC should be driven by a CURRENT source for this to be a reasonable analysis of a resonant circuit.

If you want to drive things with a voltage source, the R, L, and C need to be in series.

Either way, "interesting" things will happen at resonance.

Comment: This gives no insight into orientation (&sign) of LTspice plots.