# Is there a way to plot differentiation of frequency in LTSpice?

Tags: ltspice, delay

I'm simulating a circuit and I obtained the AC simulation (bode plot) of it. However, now I want to plot the group delay, meaning, the negative derivative of the phase in terms of frequency. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Haven't checked myself but: 
https://www.electronicspoint.com/forums/threads/ltspice-group-delay.101021/

Otherwise export your waveforms and use Matlab or Excel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest answer is to move your mouse over the right Y-axis until it becomes a ruler, right-click on it, then select `Group Delay` from the dialog.

The other, more complicated and not very useful way is to edit the waveform plot by right-clicking on the trace's label (e.g. `V(out)`), and then modify it like this:

`d( -atan( im(V(out)) / re(V(out)) ) )/ (2 * pi)`

Note that `atan2()` is not recognized, and `d()` is only recognized in the waveform arithmetic. You will also need to use a linear scale for the Y-axis if you want proper readings. See more in the help under `LTspice > Waveform Viewer > Waveform Arithmetic`.

---

In case the expression above is too much, there is a shorter alternative, `ph()`, which calculates the phase, directly, without the need for `atan()`. It's useful for plotting the phase delay, but it won't work with `d(ph())`. Be careful, though, that the result will seem wrong, as if having a changed sign:

[image: ph()]

You have to remember that LTspice plots *magnitude*, not *amplitude*, and so the phase will show 180<sup>o</sup>, which means the result has the correct polarity, it's just that the *display* is awkward. See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/521786/95619) for a similar problem.

Also, the value on the Y-axis will depend on whether `Control Panel > Waveforms > Use radian measure in waveform expressions` is checked or not. Default is unchecked, IIRC.

Comment: Thank you! I did not realize I can change "Phase" to "Group Delay" on LTSpice.